# Javascript Alert message for Geo location

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, geolocation

I am trying to give an alert message, if the user doesn't share their location and it should not insert latitude and longitude empty values into database table.

JavaScript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        var city = position.coords.locality;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + lat + " long: " + long
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + lat + "<br /> Longitude:" + long + "" });

        document.getElementById("<%= latt.ClientID %>").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("<%= lng.ClientID %>").value = position.coords.longitude;

        var div = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>
```

My ASP.NET Page load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var latt = this.latt.Value;
    var lng = this.lng.Value;

    ViewState["latt"] = latt.ToString();
    ViewState["lng"] = lng.ToString();
 }
```

ASP.NET HTML Code:

```
     <asp:HiddenField ID="latt" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="lng" runat="server" />


 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton_Attendance_login" runat="server" Visible="false" 
   ImageUrl="~/images/Attendance_login.png" 
onclick="ImageButton_Attendance_login_Click"/>
```

My Button Click Event code:

```
   protected void ImageButton_Attendance_login_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    string Status = string.Empty;
    bo.Para1 = Session["Userid"].ToString();//UserId
    bo.Para2 = Session["Name"].ToString();//UserName
    bo.Para3 = this.Page.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];//IPAddress
    bo.Para4 = "";//City
    bo.Para5 = ViewState["latt"].ToString();//Latitude
    bo.Para6 = ViewState["lng"].ToString();//Longitude
    bo.Para7 = attendancetype;//SessionType
    bl.Insert_Branches_AttendanceInfo(bo, out Status);
    if (Status == "Success")
    {
     //   Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
     //   EmployeeAttendance(attendancetype);
      //  Response.Write("<script>alert('Thank You');</script>");
    }
    else
    if (Status == "NotShareLocation")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Share Your Location');</script>");


    }

  }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I restrict from stored procedure but getting problem in mozifirefox browswer and its working in chrome. In firefox some times sharing values and some times lat and long are empty after sharing location. I am getting confused and trying from javascript. @MarkChorley

Comment: Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Share Your Location');</script>"); Message is showing after sharing location. Sometime and sometime working. @MarkChorley

Comment: I dont really understand the question, but one way to alert the user when he/she has not shared sheir location is to pass an `errorCallback(err)` callback function to geolocations `getCurrentPostion(success, error)` function. The error handling function takes an `error` object that has an error code. See the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Can you give updated your according above my javascript. @micnil